# How do I list all "Classes" defined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript

Is there an [ObjectSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby) in JavaScript?

Say I have these "classes" defined in isolated closures like this:

```
(function() {
  var Model;
  Model = (function() {
    function Model() {}
    return Model;
  })();
}).call(this);

(function() {
  var View;
  View = (function() {
    function View() {}
    return View;
  })();
}).call(this);

(function() {
  var Controller;
  Controller = (function() {
    function Controller() {}
    return Controller;
  })();
}).call(this);
```

Is there any way to look up all of those custom classes in JavaScript?  Something like:

```
Object.classes;
```

Even if they were all in the same scope, is it possible?

```
var Model;
Model = (function() {
  function Model() {}
  return Model;
})();

var View;
View = (function() {
  function View() {}
  return View;
})();
```

Or would I just need to register them manually?  Maybe like:

```
var ObjectSpace = {};
ObjectSpace.classes = [Model, View, Controller];
```

Just playing around with JavaScript/CoffeeScript and ideas from Ruby.

Comment: What kind of pattern is that? Your code in example 1 does nothing at all, and example 2 does exactly the same as `function Model() {} function View() {}`

Answer (score 4):

You would have to register them manually in order to have a list of them.

There is no such thing as a "class" in the javascript language so the language itself doesn't actually know about them.  They are conventions used with prototypes or functions to provide a behavior similar to what is supported in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

What you can do in coffeescript is

```
Classes = global.Classes = []

Classes.push class Model
    constructor: -> ...
```

or in javascript

```
global.Classes = {}

Model = Classes.Model = function(){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do as you stated:

```
    ObjectSpace = {};
    ObjectSpace.classes = [Model, View, Controller];
```

In JavaScript, class constructs are not included. You are always interacting with and inheriting from Objects directly.

An example:

```
    function Model(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
    Model.prototype.show = function() {
        alert('This model has name: '+this.name);
    };
    var model = new Model('test');
    model.show();   // 'This model has name: test'
```

When you use the `new` keyword, the js interpreter will first establish in the new instance a prototype link to the constructor function's prototype. This prototype object will be shared across all instances of, e.g., Model. If a property/method is changed on the prototype, all instances will immediately see that change, unless you do something like `Model.prototype = { show: ... }`. The reason is that you are literally making a new reference to for the prototype, but all current instances of Model point to the old reference.