# Can a ruby class statically keep track of subclasses?

Tags: ruby

My goal is this:

```
class MyBeautifulRubyClass
  #some code goes here
end

puts MyBeautifulRubyClass.subclasses #returns 0

class SlightlyUglierClass < MyBeautifulRubyClass
end

puts MyBeautifulRubyClass.subclasses #returns 1
```

hell ideally even

```
puts MyBeautifulRubyClass.getSubclasses #returns [SlightlyUglierClass] in class object form
```

I am sure this is possible, just not sure how!

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an inefficient way:

[Look up all descendants of a class in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby)

The efficient approach would use the `inherited` hook:

```
class Foo
  def self.descendants
    @descendants ||= []
  end

  def self.inherited(descendant)
    descendants << descendant
  end
end

class Bar < Foo; end
class Zip < Foo; end

Foo.descendants #=> [Bar, Zip]
```

If you need to know about descendants of descendants, you can recurse to get them:

```
class Foo
  def self.all_descendants
    descendants.inject([]) do |all, descendant|
      (all << descendant) + descendant.all_descendants
    end
  end
end

class Blah < Bar; end

Foo.descendants     #=> [Bar, Zip]
Foo.all_descendants #=> [Bar, Blah, Zip]
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to [how Rails does it](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d89a7967b5af5c87bbfc268af72287b82541d384/activesupport/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb#L32-35) as well.

Comment: Could I then call Bar.descendants? What would it take to make that work?

Comment: @Volte Create a module called something like DescendantsTracking that has the inherited method (as a regular method, not a singleton method) then "extend" Foo and Bar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it without going to ObjectSpace a la http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2992, but that may have changed--just one solution.