# How to check all classes under or using a class?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Look up all descendants of a class in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby)

So, let's say that we have:

```
class LivingBeing
  class Animal
  end

  class Bacteria
  end

  class Virus
  end
end

class Fungi < LivingBeing
end
```

How do I check what subclasses `LivingBeing` has? I know that we have `Klass.ancestors` but what's the method to see the opposite of ancestors?

Comment: 'opposite of ancestors' == subclasses

Comment: The answer you are looking for is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby I believe... interesting question though.

Comment: Another solution is to define included in your base class, and have it record every time someone subclasses it.

Comment: Note that Animal, Bacteria and Virus are not LivingBeings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built into the core Ruby language that will do what you want - you'll need to write your own. Here's an example method `subclasses_of(class_name_here)` (below) that will return a list of subclasses of a particular class for you:

```
class Mammal
end

class Human < Mammal
end

class Dog < Mammal
end

def subclasses_of input
  ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |klass| klass < input }
end

subclasses_of(Mammal)
 #=> [Human, Dog]
```

Btw, there's an answer to this question here:

http://dzone.com/snippets/objectsubclasses

Comment: There is a subclasses method for the class. `Mammal.subclasses` gives `[Human, Dog]`

Comment: Where? I tried the following: `>   Mammal.subclasses
NoMethodError: undefined method 'subclasses' for Mammal:Class
 from (irb):44
 from /Users/nat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in '<main>'`. There's also no mention of it here: http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/Module or here: http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/Class

Comment: Ah, I see... it's a rails thing: http://rdoc.info/gems/activesupport/Class#subclasses-instance_method

Comment: Yup; I noticed it while in a rails console, and verified it is not there when in irb. Thanks for the links to the docs!