# Rails force models to eager load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to be able to load an entire app so that I may find the descendants of a given class.

For example given I have the following class defined:

```
# app/models/foo_class.rb
class FooClass < MySpecialBaseClass
  # pasta code
end
```

It won't be found with:

```
irb> ObjectSpace.each_object.select { |obj| obj.is_a?(Class) && obj <= MySpecialBaseClass }
=> []
```

Until I call the const:

```
irb> FooClass
```

Then it is returned:

```
irb> ObjectSpace.each_object.select { |obj| obj.is_a?(Class) && obj <= MySpecialBaseClass } 

=> [FooClass]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This question appears to have been [addressed already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby).  Does this not work for you?

Comment: This is essentially what I am doing, but it does not address the autoload problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With **Rails 6**, [Zeitwerk](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk) became the default code loader.

Try the following for eager loading:

```
Zeitwerk::Loader.eager_load_all
```

Answer (score 41):

Well, after some digging, it actually is really simple. Just need to run the following.

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

Comment: Is it possible to put this in a config file so that it is called after initialize of Rails application. Where would you put that?

Comment: I'd like to know also: Where in the source tree does this little snippet go?

Comment: You can put `config.after_initialize { eager_load! }` in your *application.rb*, however this doesn't reload the class when calling `reload!` on the console.

Comment: Updated to the answer that @wbharding left as its more relevant for Rails 5

Answer (score 13):

After a great deal of trial and error, I recently learned that Jason Waldrip's answer is somewhat incomplete. As of Rails 5, `Rails.application.eager_load!` will indeed load all of the directories specified in `config/application.rb`. But it doesn't match Rails' actual behavior in production. To do that, one must instead mirror what Rails does:

```
Rails.configuration.eager_load_namespaces.each(&:eager_load!)
```

The salient difference between the approaches is that OPs answer won't eager load the files within app directories of `Engine`s that live in the `gems` or `vendor` folders. Whereas Rails itself *will* identify where subclasses of `Engine` exist and will see to it that the appropriate `app` subdirectories are eager-loaded.

**Behind the scenes**

Rails 5 adds eager load directories in `railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb:39`, where it runs

```
      paths.add "app",                 eager_load: true, glob: "{*,*/concerns}"
      paths.add "app/assets",          glob: "*"
      paths.add "app/controllers",     eager_load: true
      paths.add "app/channels",        eager_load: true, glob: "**/*_channel.rb"
      paths.add "app/helpers",         eager_load: true
      paths.add "app/models",          eager_load: true
      paths.add "app/mailers",         eager_load: true
```

These directories are not currently included in a default `Rails.application.eager_load!`

Comment: This is throwing /railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!': undefined method `require_dependency' for #<ActiveStorage::Engine:0x000055b98e83b3a8> (NoMethodError)

Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 11):

From [Configuring Rails Applications](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

1. config.eager_load when true Eager loads all registered
   config.eager_load_namespaces. This includes your application,
   engines, Rails frameworks and any other registered namespace.
2. config.eager_load_namespaces registers namespaces that are eager
   loaded when config.eager_load is true. All namespaces in the list
   must respond to the eager_load! method.
3. config.eager_load_paths accepts an array of paths from which Rails
   will eager load on boot if cache classes is enabled. Defaults to
   every folder in the app directory of the application.

**EDIT:**

To manually load you should be able to do something like:

```
matcher = /\A#{Regexp.escape(load_path)}\/(.*)\.rb\Z/
Dir.glob("#{load_path}/**/*.rb").sort.each do |file|
  require_dependency file.sub(matcher, '\1')
end
```

Comment: Sure, I am aware of doing it in configuration, but what about manually?