# Rails how do I check for existance of a class when not instantiated yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, meta

I have a utility class defined with a bunch of class methods.  In the Rails console, when I search for the class using `Object.const_defined?` it returns false.  But after calling one of the class methods or creating an instance of the class, `Object.const_defined?` returns true.  Is this because of some kind of lazy loading instantiation kind of thing?  Is there another way I can check for the existence of a class which will return true, even if I haven't instantiated anything yet?

Comment: You might just try eager-loading them; if the class hasn't been loaded, it hasn't been loaded, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/19839847/438992

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is kind of a hack, but it works

```
Object.const_get(:ClassName).is_a?(Class) rescue false
```

Above statement will return true if the class is defined and return false otherwise

Comment: Wouldn't `!!ClassName rescue false` be simpler?

Comment: Yeah, that's another way

Comment: How about ClassName rescue false ? ClassName is truthy if it exists =)

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to do this without exception handling?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [safe_constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-safe_constantize).

```
  your_class = "YourClassName".safe_constantize
  if your_class && your_class.class == Class
    your_class.new(options).run
  end
```