# undefined method `ancestors' on PUT with rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot

i'm testing with rspec, factory_girl and capybara. The project uses devise, i have the following method to login inside the specs:

```
def login_admin
before(:each) do
  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
  sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
end
end

def login_user
before(:each) do
  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end

end
```

Then i perform the tests on companies_controller_spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CompaniesController, :type => :controller do

let(:valid_attributes) { { "email" => Faker::Internet.email } }

login_admin

describe "GET show" do

  it "assigns the requested company as @company" do
    company = FactoryGirl.create(:company)
    get :show, {:id => company.to_param}
    expect(assigns(:company)).to eq(company)
  end
end

describe "GET edit" do
  it "assigns the requested company as @company" do
    company = FactoryGirl.create(:company)
    get :edit, {:id => company.to_param}
    expect(assigns(:company)).to eq(company)
  end
end

describe "PUT update" do
  describe "with valid params" do
    it "updates the requested company" do
      company = FactoryGirl.create(:company)
      expect_any_instance_of(company).to receive(:update).with({ "email" => "r@gmail.com" })
      put :update, {:id => company.to_param, :company => { "email" => "r@gmail.com" }}
    end
  end
end
```

But i keep getting this two errors:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `ancestors' for #<Company:0x000000059b41f0>
# ./spec/controllers/companies_controller_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>' 
line 34: expect_any_instance_of(company).to receive(:update).with({ "email" => "r@gmail.com" })
```

and

```
expected: #<Company id: 86...
got: nil
# ./spec/controllers/companies_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
line 41: expect(assigns(:company)).to eq(company)
```

This is my factory for companies:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    plan_id {}
    phone { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    facebook { Faker::Internet.url('facebook.com') }
    twitter { Faker::Internet.url('twitter.com') }
    linkedin { Faker::Internet.url('linkedin.com') }
    web { Faker::Internet.url }
 end
end
```

Comment: Stack trace would be nice :)

Comment: Added @KyleMacey! On main question.

Answer (score 25):

Just did this myself, accidentally called `expect_any_instance_of` on an *actual* instance, instead of on the class itself.

Old question, but for others finding this question, looks like OP should be using `Company` (uppercase class name) instead of `company` (lowercase reference to an instance).

`expect_any_instance_of(Company).to receive(:update).with({ "email" => "r@gmail.com" })`

To explain the error in a little more detail, `ancestors` is trying to access all of the classes from which `Company` inherits. A good example of ancestors/descendants [on this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby).

Comment: I'm using a little bit different stack (RSpec and Fabrication), but was getting the same error. I had called `allow_any_instance_of` on an object, not a class. This did it for me. Thx!

Comment: This was the correct solution for my issue. I was using `expect_any_instance_of` with `WhateverClass.new` as the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `company = FactoryGirl.create(:company)`, isn't `company` an instance on its own?

How about `Company.any_instance.expects(:update).with({ "email" => "r@gmail.com" })`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because we have to expect the actual modal/class -> here it
is Company, instead of expecting any instance of the instance (company).
so the expected line should be

`expect_any_instance_of(Company)` instead of `expect_any_instance_of(company)`