# Loading class descendants in rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to be able to see all of the class descendants from a controller when I go into the rails console locally. I have this `Api::BaseController` which all my Api controller inherit from. The issue I have is when I hop in to the rails console to check which Api controller are in the descendants, it comes up empty until I call them. This probably has something to do with how the classes in development aren't eager loaded, and they're not cached locally.

```
sample_app$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
2.1.5 :001 > Api::BaseController.descendants
 => []
2.1.5 :002 > Api::V1::FoosController
 => Api::V1::FoosController
2.1.5 :003 > Api::BaseController.descendants
 => [Api::V1::FoosController]
```

From this example, you can see when I call descendants on the `Api::BaseController` the first time, it's an empty array. After calling one of the controllers that class will be then loaded and will show up as a descendant. In this case, there could be an any number of controllers in V1 as well as V2, V3, etc...

As a stupid ugly hack, I could do

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root.join('app', 'controllers', 'api', 'v1')}/**/*.rb").each(&method(:require_dependency))
```

but I don't want to have to write that each time I enter the console. I'm also working on a gem, and definitely don't want to put this sort of code in my gem.

The other option is caching classes in development, but that causes a huge issues on it's own. Anyone have any ideas?

**Edit**
Another option would be to call `Rails.application.eager_load!`. This option would work fine if I could specify only controllers in my API folder. Then I wouldn't have to eager load the entire app, but just a small subset of controllers that I need.

Comment: Your best bet might be to look at `Rails.application.railties`, whichs holds the list of initializers. `Rails.application.eager_load!` calls `eager_load!` on each of these. Possibly just a matter of finding the right one. If you're planning on making a rails plugin, then there is probably a really easy way to access the the initializers that your plugin creates. [This blog](https://blog.engineyard.com/2010/extending-rails-3-with-railties/) discusses creating initializers for plugins, so that may help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the following post: http://avinmathew.com/using-rails-descendants-method-in-development/

In short it says the following:

In `enviroments/development.rb` add the following:

```
config.eager_load_paths += Dir['path/to/files/*.rb']
ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare do
  Dir['path/to/files/*.rb'].each {|file| require_dependency file}
end
```

The first line adds the path that should be loaded when you start your app (or console)
and the rest tells rails to reload the classes on each request.

Comment: Thanks. This was what I ended up doing. I'm just grabbing all of the controllers in the api and eager loading them. I don't think this will affect performance, just boot time is increased slightly. I basically just ripped out what the `eager_load!` method does, and altered the path

Comment: If you're using Rails 5, the reloading part should now look like : 
    Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare do
      Dir["path/to/files/*.rb"].each {|file| require_dependency file}
    end

Answer (score 3):

#### Works in Rails 5 & Rails 6:

In `environments/development.rb`:

```
Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare do
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/my_models/*.rb"].each { |file| require_dependency file }
end
```

This builds on [u/Aguardientico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664463/1038034) above.

- If requiring files not in `config.eager_load_paths` you may need to add yours [as described above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664463/1038034).
- `ActionDispatch::Reloader` is replaced with `Rails.application.reloader` (thanks to u/jean-baptiste's comment).
- `#{Rails.root}` was necessary as part of my argument to `Dir` for this to work.