# How do I get a list of all subclasses without instantiating first in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have 4 classes with the following hierarchy:

```
class MainClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class SubClassA < MainClass
  ...
end

class SubClassB < MainClass
  ...
end

class SubClassC < MainClass
  ...
end
```

How can I get a list of the subclasses of MainClass without going through and creating instances of each of the other classes?

In a fresh IRB session I can go in and say

```
irb(main)> MainClass.descendants
=> []
```

However if I go through and create instances of each subclass I'll see the following

```
irb(main)> SubClassA.new
=> #<SubClassA ...>
irb(main)> SubClassB.new
=> #<SubClassB ...>
irb(main)> SubClassC.new
=> #<SubClassC ...>
irb(main)> MainClass.descendants
=> [SubClassA(...), SubClassB(...), SubClassC(...)]
```

I'm basically looking for a way to programmaticly supply all subclasses so in the future when I want to add SubClassD, SubClassE, etc., I won't have to worry that each one is instantiated in the code before the user can see them.

Comment: I tried on rail console (rails 4.1.2). I am getting this (and not an empty list like you) :-
irb(main):012:0> MainClass.descendants 
=> [SubClassA(Table doesn't exist), SubClassB(Table doesn't exist)]

Comment: Interesting. Originally, I split my subclasses out into their own files (sub_class_a.rb, sub_class_b.rb, sub_class_c.rb) all at the same level and I was getting what I detailed above. When I consolidated the classes all in the same main_class.rb, the descendants method worked as you said.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an artefact of development mode only loading classes when first referenced: those files haven't been read by the interpreter yet - as far as ruby is concerned the classes genuinely do not exist yet

A workaround is to put

```
require_dependency "subclass_a"
require_dependency "subclass_b"
....
```

At the bottom the file for main class (outside the class definition)

Comment: Is this solution RAILS specific?

Comment: It is - both the descendants method that is misbehaving and require_dependency are rails specific.

Comment: Thank you! This did it. It wasn't even in my mind that the files weren't being loaded in development

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways you can achieve this. Either by using a gem such as the [descendants_tracker](https://github.com/dkubb/descendants_tracker):

```
class MainClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend DescendantsTracker
end

class SubClassA < MainClass 
end

...

MainClass.descendants # => [SubClassA]
```

Or you could create a custom one in your parent class like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2393750/3307520):

```
class  MainClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.descendants
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |klass| klass < self }
  end
end

class SubClassA < MainClass 
end

class SubClassB  < MainClass 
end

puts MainClass.descendants 

#=> SubClassA
    SubClassB
```

You can also check for levels of dependencies. If you want an array of the direct child of MainClass for example you could use the [`.subclasses`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Class/subclasses) class method

```
MainClass.subclasses  # => [SubClassA, SubClassB,...]
```

Now if you want more than one level depth of child classes use [`.descendants`](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/descendants). You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19187796/3307520)

Comment: `< ActiveRecord::Base` may not be relevant for this answer.

Comment: Meaning the `.subclasses` and `.descendants` methods can't be called on an ActiveRecord model?

Comment: Right, I was trying to adapt my answer to the user's question that is all.

Comment: Sorry, did not realize that.  Its okay then.

Comment: No worries, it was a genuine comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ObjectSpace#each_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) to compile a list of `MainClass`'s children:

Suppose:

```
class MainClass            ; end
class SubClassA < MainClass; end
class SubClassB < MainClass; end
class SubClassC < SubClassB; end
```

The fact that `MainClass` may be a subclass is irrelevant.

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |o| o < MainClass }.
  tap { |siblings| siblings.reject! { |klass| siblings.any? { |k| klass < k } } }
  #=> [SubClassB, SubClassA]
```