# Are there any creational design patterns that instantiate newly written classes?

Tags: object, design-patterns

Are there any creational design patterns that allow for completely new objects (as in newly written) to be instantiated without having to add a `new` statement somewhere in existing code?

Comment: Do you mean that you shouldn't have to change your program to refer to the new class at all (not just that you shouldn't have to say `new`)? Or is your question really about how to instantiate a class that you have a reference to but don't know anything about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem to solve is how to identify the class or classes to instantiate. I know of and have used three general patterns for discovering classes, which I'll call registration, self-registration and discovery by type. I'm not aware of them having been written up in a formal pattern description.

**Registration**: Each class that wants to be discovered is registered somewhere where a framework can find it:

- the class name is put in an environment variable or Java system property, in a file, etc.
- some code adds the class or its name to a singleton list early in program execution

**Self-registration**: Each class that wants to be discovered registers itself, probably in a singleton list. The trick is how the class knows when to do that.

- The class might have to be explicitly referred to by some code early in the program (e.g. [the old way of choosing a JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484227/jdbc-class-forname-vs-drivermanager-registerdriver)).
- In Ruby, the code that defines a class can register the class somewhere (or do anything else) when the class is defined. It suffices to `require` the file that contains the class.

**Discovery by type**: Each class that wants to be discovered extends or implements a type defined by the framework, or is named in a particular way. Spring autowiring class annotations are another version of this pattern.

There are several ways to find classes that descend from a given type in Java ([here's one SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class), [here's another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically)) and [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby). As with self-registration, in languages like those where classes are dynamically loaded, something has to be done to be sure the class is loaded before asking the runtime what classes are available.

Comment: Fantastic! I never knew those language constructs existed, and they were what I was looking for. (btw sorry for the late accept, life got in the way)

Answer (score 1):

One things which I think here is that someone needs to do a `new` to your newly written Class. If you are not doing that then may be some framework needs to do that.

I could remember something similar which I did in one of my side projects using Java Spring . I had an interface and multiple implementations to it. My project required to iterate over all the implementations do some processing. Now for this even I was looking for some solution with which I would not have to manually do the instantiation of that particular class or some explicit wiring of that particular class. So Spring facilitated me to do that through `@Autowired` annotation. It injected all the implementation of that interface on the fly. Eg :-

```
@Autowired
private List<IMyClass> myClassImplementations;
```

Now in the above example I can simply iterate over the list of implementations injected and I would not have to do instantiation of my new implementation every time I write a new one.

But I think in most of the cases it would be difficult to use this approach (even though it fits in my case). I would rather go with a Factory pattern in general case and try to use that for creating new instances. I know that would require new but in my perception engineering it in a way that its object is automatically created and injected is a bit an extra overhead.