# Ruby require multiple files without knowing their class names

Tags: ruby, class, methods

Let's say I have an Application that requires different files. Each file contains a single purpose "thing". I call it "thing" because I'm unsure if it will be a class or a module.

The First Thing

```
# things/one.rb
class One
  def self.do_it    
    "I'm the one"
  end
end
```

And the second

```
# things/two.rb
class Two
  def self.do_it    
    "I'm not the only one!"
  end
end
```

Now I wanna require all files in the `things`directory and execute the `do_it` method. But I wanna do this dynamically - for every thing in things folder without even knowing their Classname.

```
# app.rb
Dir["things/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

Keep in Mind: I simply wanna execute the code in the things files - it's not necessary that they are Classes or Modules

Comment: "I simply wanna execute the code in the things files - it's not necessary that they are Classes or Modules" – That's exactly what `require` does: it executes the code in the file.

Comment: Note: You need `require_relative`

Comment: Rather than referring to "thing", you mean each file contains a module that may be a class. "wanna" is not a word.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably do this for a number of reasons, but the most important is that you're under no obligations to declare a single class in any given file, or a class at all. You've got the right idea with loading in all files in a particular directory, but if you need to operate on those there's two ways to crack that nut.

The easiest way is to declare these classes as a subclass of some already known parent. ActiveSupport has the [`descendents`](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/descendants) method to reflect on a particular class, that's part of Rails, but you can also do it [the hard way if you have to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby).

The second easiest way is to correlate the names with the classes in them, and then convert filenames to class-names algorithmically. This is how the Rails autoloader works. `cat.rb` contains `Cat`, `bad_dog.rb` contains `BadDog` and so on.

If you look more closely at how things like Test::Unit work they take the first approach, any declared test subclasses are executed before the Ruby process terminates. It's a fairly simple system that puts no constraints on what the files are called or where and how the classes are declared.

Rails leans towards the second approach where the path communicates intent. This makes finding files more predictable but requires more discipline on the part of the developer to conform to that standard.

They both have merit. Pick the one that works for your use case.

Comment: Very interesting! One way to do it would be : `classes_before = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a; Dir["things/*.rb"].each {|file| require_relative file }; classes_after = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a; do_it_classes = (classes_after - classes_before).select{|klass| klass.respond_to?(:do_it)}`

Comment: Do be careful with that approach as you're expecting those files to immediately instantiate any classes whereas that might not be the case if you're dealing with `autoload` declarations or other forms of lazy loading, plus dynamic programming that might factory produce classes on-demand.

Comment: True. The OP didn't mention `autoload` though, and said that there was one thing for each file. I realize my code doesn't take modules into accounts, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm just adding caveats here because when it comes to Ruby, there's a *lot* of liberty given to the programmer. Without house-rules, standards like I've described, it's very hard to figure out exactly what to do. Your code's a good example of how to dig around *if* everything is correctly loaded.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation!